# Integrating Google Forms in Android WebView, SignIn button not working

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I am working on my first android project which is based on Google Forms.
I've done pretty much everything except my main part which is showing forms in webview. The form is getting display but the Sign In button is not clickable.

```
public class cadexpo extends AppCompatActivity {
private static WebView browser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadexpo);
    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    browser.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();
    WebSettings browser = browser.getSettings();
    browser.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VLKIncq9bTJnWqxbOHc3foTeSLykP7AQyL0Si1cIQ1I");
```

Please help me in fixing it.

Comment: post code rather then posting image of code. it will be easy for every one to help you out.

Comment: yea i was posting that but the code block was leaving few lines of my code and i dont know how to fix it.... btw this is my first question, will surely keep  this in mind for my future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable javascript for webview

```
WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: can  you fit that thing here?

.
public class cadexpo extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadexpo);
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
         browser.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();
//        WebSettings browser = browser.getSettings();
        browser.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VLKIncq9bTJnWqxbOHc3foTeSLykP7AQyL0Si1cIQ1I");

Comment: Add this line above browser.loadUrl()

Comment: its already above browser.loadUrl(); .... Error now is valiable webSetings is never user. and no changes in output

Comment: OK got it, Did a small mistake in that code. Thank you for the response :)